# In NextJS, do non-page components get rendered server side?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm kind of new to NextJS. trying to understand how sub-components are being rendered and if server side handlers such as **getServerSideProps** apply to them? my use case is that I am trying to pre-load some data server-side per sub-component. is this a valid practice?

Comment: Page components are pre-rendered by default. If you statically import some other component into the page component, then it will also get pre-rendered. To opt out of this, you can [dynamically import it](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#nextdynamic) and set the `ssr` flag to `false`. Data fetching functions like `getServerSideProps` and `getStaticProps` can only be used on page components though.